# Adding 1 to L elements in list, starting at random location

Tags: python

This is the question:
Represent a genome of size G using a list with exactly G elements, where each element contains relevant information about that position, e.g., how many times the nucleotide at that position was sequenced. To simulate the sequencing process once, follow these steps:
• Set all the elements in the list to 0 (to mark that each nucleotide has been sequenced 0 times).
• Randomly select starting locations for R reads of size L, and for each read update the number of times
the nucleotides covered by the read were sequenced.

so far I have this:

```
genome = [0]*G
for x in range(R):
    randlocation = random.randint(0,G-L)
    genome = genome[0:randlocation] + [x+1 for x in genome[randlocation:(randlocation+L)]] + genome[(randlocation+L):] 
print genome
```

but this is too slow for the G, R, and L values we need to test it on (3000000, 40000, 500). Any help speeding this up would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't recreate new lists all the time (list slicing creates copies), just increment each element as needed in a nested `for` loop:

```
genome = [0]*G
for x in range(R):
    randlocation = random.randint(0,G-L)
    for i in range(randlocation, randlocation+L):
        genome[i] += 1
print genome
```

Using numpy is likely going to be even faster... since you can use vectorized operations on slices directly: something like `genome[randlocation:randlocation+L] += 1` (but using views rather than copies here)

Answer (score 0):

While Julien's answer is efficient in its use of RAM, there's a faster way in plain Python. Use a list comprehension to perform the addition, and use slice assignment to copy the result back to the genome.

```
import random

# Seed the randomizer so we can get consistent timings
random.seed(42)

G, R, L = 3000000, 40000, 500
genome = [0] * G

for x in range(R):
    loc = random.randint(0, G-L)
    genome[loc:loc + L] = [x+1 for x in genome[loc:loc + L]]
```

On my old 2GHz 32 bit machine running Python 3.6 that takes about 7 ± 0.5 seconds. In contrast, using this loop to perform the update

```
for x in range(R):
    loc = random.randint(0, G-L)
    for i in range(loc, loc + L):
        genome[i] += 1
```

takes around 18 ± 0.5 seconds. But it does use more RAM since it needs to create an `L` sized lists on every loop. Of course, Python will recycle the memory used for those lists, and since `L` is only 500, that RAM use isn't worth worrying about.

---

FWIW, if we do this using Numpy, we can drop the time down to 2 seconds or less. Another benefit is that Numpy arrays use native datatypes (machine integers in this case), so the RAM overheads are less than using lists of Python objects.

```
import numpy as np
import random

# Seed the randomizer so we can get consistent timings
random.seed(42)

G, R, L = 3000000, 40000, 500

genome = np.zeros(G, dtype=np.int)

for x in range(R):
    loc = random.randint(0, G-L)
    genome[loc:loc + L] += 1
```

I'm not a Numpy expert, so there may be an even more efficient way to do this.